Flutter - Design
I'm currently working on developing an app using Flutter. I found a design on Dribbble that I'd like to replicate, but I'm unsure of the best approach. My initial thought was to use a PageView, but I'm worried about the outcome.
Here's the link to the Dribbble page featuring the design I want to replicate: https://dribbble.com/shots/20580468-Proximity-based-Social-Media-Mobile-IOS-App
I'm relatively new to app development and consider it a passion of mine. I'm seeking the simplest way to replicate this design with the best possible result. It doesn't have to be an exact match, but I want it to look similar.
I'm open to any advice and would appreciate any help. Feel free to comment or answer this post, and I'll respond as quickly as possible, usually within the day.

I've been working on the design, and I finally found a way to do it! If you want the full code of the Flutter app that reproduces the design in my question, check out my GitHub repository where I posted it.
Happy coding to everyone :)
